# Error while running tomcat on Intellij Idea

Tags: java, tomcat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35sYX.jpg)I have created a Java Enterprise Web Application & using the tomcat server, but while i'm trying to run a jsp file, it says : Error running 'Tomcat 9.0.16 (Ubuntu)': port out of range:-1. port : 8080 is free, can anyone tell me the solution.

I have checked port, it is okay, changed the port, restart nothing works!

Comment: Port 8080 is free, but apparently you're trying to use the port -1, which is out of range.

Comment: how?! i'm using port 8080 & i have configured this port in tomcat server. https://imgur.com/a/F58eNIW look at here

Comment: I don't know, but that's what the message says. Have you tried downloading a fresh version of Tomcat, unzipping it, and configure IntelliJ to use that new server?

Comment: I have downloaded it via terminal (ubuntu) & config with intelliJ, tomcat is working fine if i run via terminal, but if i want to run in intelliJ, it shows this error

Answer (score 2):

Sry if it is too late, but for future reference I found a solution for this.

In the Tomcat Installation folder there is a file `config/server.xml`. In it is a tag `Server` with the property `port`. This is set to -1 by default which disables the shutdown port.

From the [Apache Tomcat 9 Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/server.html):

> The TCP/IP port number on which this server waits for a shutdown command. Set to -1 to disable the shutdown port.
>
> Note: Disabling the shutdown port works well when Tomcat is started using Apache Commons Daemon (running as a service on Windows or with jsvc on un*xes). It cannot be used when running Tomcat with the standard shell scripts though, as it will prevent shutdown.bat|.sh and catalina.bat|.sh from stopping it gracefully.

I guess IntelliJ uses this port to stop the Tomcat Server and therefore complains if it isn't set. Maybe Jetbrains considers to give more information on this to allow users to find the problem by themselves.

Comment: @Robbo_UK well, set the shutdown port to an unused port and run it!

Answer (score 1):

In **Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf.xml**

Set to 1 which enable the shutdown port.

```
From: <Server port="-1"
To: <Server port="1"
```

---

### Then, free or chosse new ports for shutdown

Also we have to make sure that the http and jmx ports are not in use; or use other than 8080 and 1099 respectively.

**Option 1:**

*In Windows:*

Find the PID that uses port http y jmx.

```
netstat -aon | find "8080"
netstat -aon | find "1099"
```

Kill the process.

```
taskkill /F /PID xxxx
taskkill /F /PID xxxx
```

**Option 2 (recommended): Choose new ports**

IDE > Edit Configurations > Run/Debug Configurations

- From **HTTP port**: 8080 | To: 8082
- From **JMX port**: 1099 | To: 1102

[image]

GL

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58748830/5279996)

Answer (score 0):

I use Linux Mint, so the following successfully helped me:

https://tecadmin.net/install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu/

It probably has to do with custom edits applied from the Ubuntu team to "Tomcat 9.0.16 (Ubuntu)".  I applied version 9.0.22 of Tomcat with the above guide.

Also, since you use IntelliJ, you should probably set the target port to 8081 or similar, instead of 8080.